# Selenium cloud execution on a machine without code or IDE

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium, jenkins, github

I set up my Selenium project (Maven, Java, TestNG) in GitHub repo and it is connected to Jenkins. I am able to execute the Maven project via Jenkins and do the testing. This requires all dependant tools (Maven,Java,Jenkins) set up in my local machine.

But we have a requirement to do this in the cloud. I know we can use Selenium Grid-Docker, BrowserStack or GCP to execute the tests in the cloud but what we need is to have everything installed in the cloud and any external user with access being able to execute any test via UI or executable file without installing anything in user's local machine.

Is this possible at all? If yes,how?

I searched a lot and couldn't find anything. One of my friends said it can be done using AWS but doesn't know how. I just need guidance on the path to take here and I'm willing to learn and implement it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this my deploying code to AWS-EC2.

Here's what I did.
I created a TestNG-Maven project and uploaded to GitHub. Then created a AWS-EC2 t2.micro linux instance and installed Chrome and Jenkins in it. I accessed Jenkins from my local machine and connected it to GitHub repo. From Jenkins when I build the project everything was getting downloaded in EC2 and execution happened in EC2. This will be chrome-headless execution.

Comment: @dspencer Edited and added full details. Thanks.